# Combining python print statements

Tags: python, printing, termcolor

Is it possible to combine the the following two statements into one?

```
print(colored(score,"green"),end=" ")
print(colored(tokens,"green"))
```

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but too broad. What do you want to achieve, what is the current output and what's keeping you from doing what you want. your question needs editing

Comment: I'd suggest you look into `str.format()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply add the last item to the first print statement:

```
print(colored(score,"green"), colored(tokens,"green"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As they're both green you can combine the strings and then colour them:

```
output = '{} {}'.format(score, tokens)
print(colored(output, 'green'))
```